# Am I writing this method the right way?

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I've got an `ArrayList` called `conveyorBelt`, which stores orders that have been picked and placed on the conveyor belt. I've got another `ArrayList` called `readyCollected` which contains a list of orders that can be collected by the customer.

What I'm trying to do with the method I created is when a `ordNum` is entered, it returns true if the order is ready to be collected by the customer (thus removing the collected order from the `readyCollected`). If the order hasn't even being picked yet, then it returns false.

I was wondering is this the right way to write the method...

```
  public boolean collectedOrder(int ordNum)
  {
      int index = 0;
      Basket b = new Basket(index);
      if(conveyorBelt.isEmpty()) {
          return false;
      }
      else {
          readyCollected.remove(b);
          return true;
      }
  }
```

Comment: We can't see a lot of what's going on. What is Basket? Is the equals method for it well defined? What is type is readyCollected?

Comment: You're not using `ordNum`, so obviously something is wrong. Also, b is always `Basket(0)`. Maybe it should be `Basket(ordNum)`? We need to see more of your code!

Comment: @Andrew White, Basket is class that holds a collection of produts (this is used for the arrayList).

Comment: @Amir Rachum, Oh snap I never realised that i'm not using the ordNum. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused since you're not using `ordNum` at all.

If you want to confirm operation of your code and generally increase the reliability of what you're writing, you should check out [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) and the Java frameworks available for this.

Comment: Thanks, Amir Rachum pointed out i'm not using ordNum at all. But is there anything else wrong with what I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using an `ArrayList`, but I think that this is fundamentally the wrong way to think about the problem.  An `ArrayList` is good for storing a complete sequence of data without gaps where you are only likely to add or remove elements at the very end.  It's inefficient to remove elements at other positions, and if you have just one value at a high index, then you'll waste a lot of space filling in all lower positions with null values.

Instead, I'd suggest using a `Map` that associates order numbers with the particular order.  This more naturally encodes what you want - every order number is a key associated with the order.  `Map`s, and particularly `HashMap`s, have very fast lookups (expected constant time) and use (roughly) the same amount of space no matter how many keys there are.  Moreover, the time to insert or remove an element from a `HashMap` is expected constant time, which is extremely fast.

As for your particular code, I agree with Brian Agnew on this one that you probably want to write some unit tests for it and find out why you're not using the `ordNUm` parameter.  That said, I'd suggest reworking the system to use `HashMap` instead of `ArrayList` before doing this; the savings in time and code complexity will really pay off.

Comment: Do you mind if you can write a quick Unit Test for this method for me? I'm still new to Java (been studying it since October) and haven't got to that stage yet.

Comment: @Mayfield- A unit test is just a fancy name for a function that (usually, as part of a bigger test framework) just exercises a particular function in as many ways as you can think of to try to smoke out any latent bugs it might have.  Even without using something like JUnit4, you should be able to write one of these yourself.  It's a good habit to get into, so I'd suggest doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, why isn't this sufficient :

```
  public boolean collectedOrder(int ordNum)   {         
      return (readyCollected.remove(ordNum) != null);
  }
```

Why does the conveyorBelt ArrayList even need to be checked?

Comment: Thanks for the correction Amir Afghani. It is being checked because, when the product is put into the conveyorBelt, I'm checking that there is an order there. Hmmm, to think about that might not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, you most likely need to be using `ordNum`.

Aside from that the best answer anyone can give with the code you've posted is "perhaps". Your logic certainly looks correct and ties in with what you've described, but whether it's doing what it should depends entirely on your implementation elsewhere.

As a general pointer (which may or may not be applicable in this instance) you should make sure your code deals with edge cases and incorrect values. So you might want to flag something's wrong if `readyCollected.remove(b);` returns false for instance, since that indicates that `b` wasn't in the list to remove.

As already pointed out, take a look at unit tests using [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) for this type of thing. It's easy to use and writing thorough unit tests is a very good habit to get into.